# Obj C - Give Variable new memory address everytime method is called

Tags: objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a way to reallocate a variable to give it a different memory address inside a for loop

I am using ARC

The main part of the code is here;

```
- (void) deal:(BOOL)isDefault
{
    player = [[Player alloc] init];
    appDel = [[BlackjackAppDelegate alloc] init];
    appDel.playersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    appDel.discardPile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Initial Deal

    int i; // Current Card for player
    int j; // Current Player

    if (isDefault)
    {
        startingCardCount = 7;
        numberOfPlayers = 4;
    }

    for (int temp = 0; temp < numberOfPlayers; temp++)
    {
        [self addPlayersWithNumber:temp];
    }

    // Loops through number of cards supposed to be in hand (if default settings: use 7 cards)
    for (i = 0; i < startingCardCount; i++)
    {
        // Loop through number of players (if default settings: use 4 players)
        for (j = 0; j < numberOfPlayers; j++)
        {
            //Player *tempPlayer = [appDel.playersArray objectAtIndex:j];
            Card *card = [Card generateCardWithAppDel:appDel];
            Player *tempPlayer = [appDel.playersArray objectAtIndex:j];

            [tempPlayer.hand addObject:card];
            [self refreshPlayerIndex:j withPlayer:tempPlayer];
        }
    }
}
- (void) addPlayersWithNumber:(NSInteger)playerNumber
{
    // THIS VARIABLE I WANT TO "REALLOCATE" EACH TIME THIS METHOD IS CALLED
    Player *tempPlayer = [[Player alloc] init];
    tempPlayer.number = playerNumber;

    [appDel.playersArray addObject:player];
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give me, I really need this to be fixed as, I am adding to an array and manipulating in a different part of the deal method (as seen)

EDIT:

Player.h:

```
//
//  Player.h
//  Blackjack
//
//  Created by Zach Ross-Clyne on 02/03/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Avicode. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BlackjackAppDelegate.h"

@interface Player : NSObject
{
    NSInteger type;
    NSInteger number;
    NSMutableArray *hand;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *hand;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger type;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number;

@end
```

Player.m

```
//
//  Player.m
//  Blackjack
//
//  Created by Zach Ross-Clyne on 02/03/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Avicode. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize number, hand, type;

- (id) init
{
    hand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You posted three `for` loops. What code is relevant, and what do you mean by a different memory address?

Comment: You need to be more precise about exactly what you mean. BTW: there's an obvious bug in the inner for loop where you create a `tempPlayer` only to overwrite it on the next line. Either you create your tempPlayer (alloc+init dance) or you retrieve it from some array, but not both.

Comment: @woz The first for loop, that one calls the `addPlayersWithNumber` method, which has the variable... And in the Debug console it says `tempPlayer = (Player *) 0x0724ccc0` - I want to change the `0x0724ccc0` bit each time its called, otherwise its the "same" object in the array when it gets added

Comment: @verec I did wonder about that bug, but still allocated and initiated anyway haha (thats not where the problem is though, its the first for loop)

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: Yea, what's the problem? It sound work fine. You don't have to worry about memory addresses. That's the point of using Objective-C instead of assembly.

Comment: Each tempPlayer that gets added to the playersArray has the same memory address, so when I go to change one of them, they all change.

Comment: What does the `Player` class look like? Can you post that?

Comment: Yes sure, check now should be there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting a bug. Look at the following:

```
Player *tempPlayer = [[Player alloc] init];
tempPlayer.number = playerNumber;

[appDel.playersArray addObject:player];
```

What you're doing there is:

1. creating a Player, `tempPlayer`;
2. adding the instance variable, `player` to your `playersArray`

So each `tempPlayer` that you create is unique and none of them is ever put into your array.

Comment: If that's the only mistake, I can see how he made it. I have been looking at this for a few minutes and didn't even notice. Nice catch!

Comment: OOOOOOOOOHHHHHH DEAR!! How did I miss that

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne, you should also fix your init method. You should have an "if (self = [super init])" line in there.

Comment: and Where would I put it?

Answer (score 1):

```
tempPlayer.number = playerNumber;
[appDel.playersArray addObject:player];
```

Should be:

```
tempPlayer.number = playerNumber;
[appDel.playersArray addObject:tempPlayer];
```